# generate schema in .net core 3.1

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, schema

I want to generate an Schema code for category pages as well as product pages and contact us.
There are many packages. I am a little confused in choosing the best package. Please help me in choosing the attributed package for making Schema .
Is there a need to create a model for the Schema or does it use the information on the page?

If there is a documentary, please put the link
thanks

Comment: What is schema??

Comment: Please take a look at [link](https://Schema.org)